# Mimicking the title of Association for Computing Machinery (ACM) Template

Tags: titles, abstract

All,

My inquiry is hopefully simple enough. I'm curious how I can mimic the title format of the [ACM large 1-column format template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/acm-publications) without actually using the template.

Assume I have a basic template like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\title{A Somewhat Long Title to this Example Document}
\author{First M. Last}
\affil{College University}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\abstract{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vehicula ultricies odio vel efficitur. Curabitur bibendum lorem id nisi sagittis, id rutrum dolor facilisis. Sed vitae lacinia risus. Vestibulum a sem consequat erat placerat imperdiet. Suspendisse a eros et augue feugiat iaculis. Duis vel metus ut massa tincidunt vehicula sed et nibh. Aenean id nisl pulvinar, dignissim lacus in, mollis neque. Cras at purus vitae elit semper imperdiet quis et magna.}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

How can I get the title and abstract to look something like this?

[image: I'd like something like this]

I'd still like to keep the bottom `\hrule`, but omitted it from the screengrab because I don't need or want all those additional ACM parameters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a one time deal, or do you need this multiple times?

Comment: I just need it for the title, author, and abstract field to begin a document.

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by hand completely with the help of definitions in the original class file.

[image: samAcmMaketitle]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
{\usefont{T1}{pnc}{m}{n}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\thispagestyle{plain}
{\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\raggedright 
A Somewhat Long Title to this Example Document \par
}
{
    \vskip 13.5pt\relax \normalsize\fontsize{10}{12}\rightskip0pt plus1fill\selectfont
    First M. Last, College University\par
}
    \hbox{\vrule height .2pt width 39.14pc}
{
    \vskip 8.5pt \footnotesize 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit. Nunc vehicula ultricies odio vel efficitur.
    Curabitur bibendum lorem id nisi sagittis, id rutrum
    dolor facilisis. Sed vitae lacinia risus. Vestibulum a
    sem consequat erat placerat imperdiet. Suspendisse a eros
    et augue feugiat iaculis. Duis vel metus ut massa
    tincidunt vehicula sed et nibh. Aenean id nisl pulvinar,
    dignissim lacus in, mollis neque. Cras at purus vitae
    elit semper imperdiet quis et magna.\par
}
    \hbox{\vrule height .2pt width 39.14pc}
}

    \blinddocument

    \end{document}
```

*Disclaimer: As this is using original class code, this is a wild mixture of low-level TeX and a bit of LaTeX. Using this for real documents is not recommended.*

Comment: I thank you for your help, since TeX/LaTeX code can be a bit unintuitive. My hope is to extend this into the `\maketitle` command and definitely find a seamless way to include multiple authors. I'm wanting to move this into a latex template for Markdown too, but this is an excellent place to start.